# How to stop Windows 7 program from always being on top?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, alt-tab, focus, window-focus

I upgraded `Foxit reader` to a new version, and now its window always has the focus.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will not switch now to another window.

The only way to switch away from `Foxit reader` is to minimise it.

### Is there any setting in the registry (or elsewhere) I can set to change this behaviour?